# php how to convert day string to the nearest date of current week

Tags: php

I want to show the date of the current week if the variable is the day string
so if the variable is Friday then the date must be 2020-07-03 and if today is Thursday and the variable is Thursday then the date must be 2020-07-09

```
$today= \Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to code this? If so please show us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In core PHP, there is an awesome function called `strtotime()`. It can be used to serve the purpose,

```php
$dayOfTheWeek = 'Wednesday';
$ts = strtotime('next ' . $dayOfTheWeek);
echo date('Y-m-d', $ts);
```

I hope this helps.